# UploadedFile::getInstances giving empty array in and file upload not working in yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

If I use the field as below to upload files and when I print $_FILES in controller, the result is `empty`.

```
<?php echo $form->field($userformmodel, 'user_images[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'class' => 'multi with-preview accept-gif|jpg|png|jpeg']); ?>
```

Whereas, if I give a static input as below and print $_FILES in my controller then I am getting the array which is `not empty`.

```
 <input type="file" class="multi with-preview accept-gif|jpg|png|jpeg MultiFile-applied" name="user_images[]" multiple="" value="">
```

What could be the issue. Why am I getting empty array if I use yii model for generating input field?

Comment: what do you get in post?

Comment: @InsaneSkull I have observed that if I use multifile plugin in that case I am getting an empty array. If I remove the mutli file plugin i.e, if I remove the class multi with-preview  then I am getting an array with values. Why is it so? I didn't understand

Comment: Please add the controller codes